# How remove a div generated from a foreach loop after clicking in 'X'

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i´m using MVC and I have a page where the info was generated from a foreach loop, tha shows the model´s property.

```
 @foreach (var chassi in Model.Chassis)
                {
                    <div class="chassi">
                        @chassi
                        <img src="~/assets/icons/exclude.svg" alt="Remove chassis"/>
                    </div>
                }
```

[image]

I have to do this 'X' works, to remove this div and remove the info from the model that this page is receving.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the parent

```
<img onclick="remove(this.parentNode);" />
```

or if you have multi parent

```
<img onclick="remove(this.parentNode.parentNode);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by following these steps:

- Assign `id` to each `div` element via the same loop.
- Add `onclick` handler to `img` element.
- This handler, when clicked on image icon, will give you access to the `event`.
- Access the desired `div` by calling `event.target.parentNode` and make its `display` property `none` to hide it or call `remove()` to remove it from the dom.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can try something like this (you can merge the JS in the onclick with your delete image):

```html
<div class="chassi">
  Test
  <button onClick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Delete me</button>

</div>
<div class="chassi">
  Test
  <button onClick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Delete me</button>

</div>
```